# How to import accented public TSV Google Spreadsheet data into R

Tags: r, encoding, google-sheets

If I try to import a public spreadsheet like this example into R:

[image]

using:

```
library(httr)     
url <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qIOv7MlpQAuBBgzV9SeP3gu0jCyKkKZapPrZHD7DUyQ/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=tsv"
GET(url)
```

I get the wrong accented words, as you can see in this picture:

[image]

How can I get the right encode?

I know I can use [googlesheets](https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets) package, but for public data I prefer to work with direct download, so I don't have to handle user login authentication and token refresh.

Comment: For public data, there's no need to authenticate with the `googlesheets` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why `httr::GET` do not work, but this works:

```
data <- utils::read.csv(url, header=TRUE, sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a *nix operating system you could use

```
curl -o data.tsv 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qIOv7MlpQAuBBgzV9SeP3gu0jCyKkKZapPrZHD7DUyQ//pub?gid=0&single=true&output=tsv'
```